# helm: access dict via functions arguments

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

The fully qualified name of images from the chart including subcharts is returned via a function. The name of the function is `custom.image.fullname`.

The function gets a list as argument. At the first position is the dict, which is passed to the subchart. Second is the name of the key that is to be accessed in the dict. The call looks like this:

`image: {{ include "custom.image.fullname" (list . "busybox" ) }}`

The funcion is in the `_helpers.tpl` of my root chart and looks like this:

```yaml
{{- define "custom.image.fullname" -}}
{{- $top := index . 0 -}}
{{- $name := index . 1 -}}

{{- $registry := required "No registry in Values.global.uctl.provided.registry.value defined" $top.Values.global.uctl.provided.registry.value -}}
{{- $image := get $top (printf "Values.global.serviceDescriptor.%s.image.repository" $name) }}
{{- $tag := get $top (printf "Values.global.serviceDescriptor.%s.image.tag" $name) }}

{{- printf "%s/%s:%s" $registry $image $tag -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Here the following dict is available as a data base:

```yaml
global:
  serviceDescriptor:
    utils:
      image:
        repository: library/busybox
        tag: latest
  uctl:
    provided:
      registry:
        value: docker.io
```

The returned value of my function contains only the container image registry like `docker.io/`. I assume that the `get` function does not return a value. So I already tried `index` and get a nil pointer error:

```yaml
{{- $image := index $top "Values" "global" "serviceDescriptor" $name "image" "repository" }}
{{- $tag := index $top "Values" "global" "serviceDescriptor" $name "image" "tag" }}
```

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: templates/deployment.yaml:36:21: executing "deployment.yaml" at <include "custom.image.fullname" (list . "busybox")>: error calling include: template: templates/_helpers.tpl:180:14: executing "custom.image.fullname" at <index $top "Values" "global" "serviceDescriptor" $name "image" "repository">: error calling index: index of nil pointer
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can access the values of my dict if the path to value is dependent on the variable `$name`?

Comment: Two things I'd double-check: at the point you're making the call, is `.` still the top-level Helm object (are you inside a `range` or `with` block)?  In the calls you show the service name is `busybox` but in the sample values file you have `utils`, do these match in your real setup?